# Need help replacing prefix of words in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I make let's say like a : function(word, n, prefix) in which the first "n" words of the "word" will be replaced by the "prefix" ? I don't wanna use Python's replace method.
Thank you

Comment: Does replacing a word with a prefix actually mean prepending the prefix string to the word?

Answer (score 0):

Simply

```
def function(word, n, prefix):
    return prefix + word[n:]
```

Notice that strings are *immutable*, so you are actually creating a new string.

---

Just for fun, you can also use a `bytearray` object, which is *mutable*

```
def function(word, n, prefix):
    word[:n] = [ord(i) for i in prefix]
    return word

>>> word = bytearray("12345", 'utf-8')
>>> function(word, 3, "abc")
bytearray(b'abc45')
>>> function(word, 3, "abc").decode('utf-8')
'abc45'
```

Comment: The second version is going to be pretty confusing if either `word` or `prefix` contains any non-ASCII characters. Especially since in the latter case you're going to get an error about `ValueError: byte must be in range(0, 256)`, while in the former case you may get mojibake or you may get a `UnicodeDecodeError` far from where the problem occurred, and none of these are very debuggable.

Comment: By the way, why not just `word[:n] = prefix.encode()`?

Comment: @abarnert awesome, always eager to learning new things :) ! Idk, I felt it is interesting to show how you can't manipulate strings and but *can* bytearrays. But truly that is not some code to put in your script, its "just for fun" haha. About `.encode()` the idea was to give some intuition about the bytes behind it. Just `encode()` would seem like a blackbox maybe